# How can I embed hidden data in a web page and recover it using the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that draws data from several other local (same origin) web pages.  I collect the data from these other web pages using XMLHttpRequest.  I then use the DOM to parse out the needed data from each page.  There is one piece of data that I would like to include in each of the other local pages (i.e., in the DOM for each of the other local pages), however, I don't want that data visible when the web page is viewed.  (Visible in the source code is OK, just not in the rendered HTML).  I can think of a couple of ways of doing that.  However, I am not enammered with any of them.  I'm wondering what suggestions others might have.  Thanks for any input.

Comment: You're populating the dom with ajax, and *then* scraping it back up?... this is backwards.

Comment: If you are _using_ the data that you retrieved via ajax (XHR) in more javascript running on the page, just save it in a javascript var, there's no need to add it to the DOM.

Comment: They are loading HTML from a different page via AJAX and then scraping that for data.

Comment: So load the HTML and create element nodes, but never attach them to the page DOM. Extract the desired data and save it as javascript vars/objects/whatever-is-appropriate. Even if it's easiest to create them by setting an `innerHTML` then you can still immediately detach the subtree from the page.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- [**The `hidden` attribute**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute):

  > All [HTML elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#html-elements) may have the [`hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) content attribute
  >   set. The [`hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute is a [boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute). When
  >   specified on an element, it indicates that the element is not yet, or
  >   is no longer, directly relevant to the page's current state, or that
  >   it is being used to declare content to be reused by other parts of the
  >   page as opposed to being directly accessed by the user. User agents
  >   should not render elements that have the [`hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute
  >   specified.
- [**The `template` element**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element)

  > The [`template`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element) element is used to declare fragments of HTML that
  >   can be cloned and inserted in the document by script.
  >
  > In a [rendering](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element), the template element [represents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) nothing.
- [**Comments**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments)

Depending on the semantics, you can choose one or another. Or even combine them:

```
<template hidden><!-- Hidden data --></template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned to get through AJAX request, it is in your control where to show or not.

Once you get the result through AJAX, you can store in your script to do some manipulation or show in HTML page itself with parent tag as visible false, so that end user cannot see (except Source code viewing).

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a simple hidden div?

`<div id="hiddenData" style="display:none;">...</div>`

To be honest, it seems like the way you are passing around data is kind of a hack already, so I don't see any real need to be fancy.

Comment: CSS in not semantic. The `...` would still be considered relevant content of the page.

Comment: Well, the alternative - your suggested hidden attribute - assumes they can use HTML 5, which may not be the case. They should really focus on fixing whatever architectural issue drove them to use such a hack in the first place, TBH.